# What does a for (;;) loop do

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

In a c/c++ file I discovered a strange for loop

```
for (;;) {...}
```

I don't know if this runs once, infinetly or works in some other way
Source: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jejb/efitools.git/tree/PreLoader.c Line 87

Comment: The same as a `while(true)`-loop.

Comment: `for(;;)` is equivqlent to `while(1)`. Its an infinite loop.

Comment: thanks. I was not sure and found nothing on the web

Comment: You could have tried it yourself.

Comment: I created a sample code snippet, but it failed to compile

Comment: The forever alone loop.

Answer (score 1):

The for(;;) loop will continue forever until some command inside the loop causes it to terminate.

Some examples of such commands would be "break", or "return"

Answer (score 1):

In the Linux kernel, infinite loops are written like this, instead of the usual `while(true)` or `while(1)` in other projects. This is a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

That is an **infinite loop**. It's an ordinary `for` loop with no condition expression. It is equivalent to `while(1)`. It is a bit odd to the eyes of nearly all `C` and `C++` programmers, and should be avoided. I think people from a `C/C++` background are more likely to prefer `while(1)` rather than `for(;;)`.

K&R 2nd ed 3.5:

> is an ``infinite'' loop, presumably to be broken by other means, such
>   as a break or return. Whether to use while or for is largely a matter
>   of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop, equivalent to while(true). When no termination condition is provided, the condition defaults to true.